# How does nWoD's Secret History (The God Machine) chapter relate to the other core books?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

Chapter 1: The Secret History (Unrecorded History: Voice of the Angel) of the new World of Darkness core book tells a story about a god-machine, angels, ancients, their children and whatnot.

How does this part relate to the "core themes" (mages, vampires, werewolves, etc) of nWoD? Is it just flavor text, "mysterious/mad rambling", or is this a "backbone" for the whole game world, with clues to be found here and there? If so, what are these clues and which books contain them?

Comment: @Pureferret About the bounty: this is a [tag:new-world-of-darkness] question currently, which means it wants 1e answers. Do you think it's worth asking a new question that has a 2e focus?

Comment: @Jadasc not certain ... The accepted answer already mentions gmc/2E in passing so I'm not sure what the value would be splitting it. Also 1e and 2e are very closely linked (cmiir) in fluff, which is the focus of this question.

Comment: @Pureferret Okeydoke. Just wanted to see whether it would be warranted.

Comment: @Jadasc I think it should probably have both tags, also I updated your answer to say Descent not Fallen ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### In the first edition of the New World of Darkness, the presence of the God Machine was subtly hinted at in the other core books.

**Danse Macabre**, a sourcebook for *Vampire: The Requiem*, details a mini-Covenant called the **Holy Engineers**, who receive transmissions from the God Machine that they strive to interpret. The intended effect is "oracles in reverse" — they'll receive answers and missions to undertake with the goal of figuring out the question or inciting incidents.

**Imperial Mysteries**, the archmastery book for *Mage: The Awakening*, says this:

> It might also be possible to secretly change the world into an occult engine for a Fallen god: a Mystery Play that returns it to power. The ententes believe at least one such "God Machine" already exists.

The following contains spoilers for "These Mortal Engines" in the *Promethean: the Created* sourcebook, **Saturnine Night**.

> The God Machine, or an aspect of it, makes an appearance at the climax of this adventure, "offering" the player characters a chance to become human. The choice to activate or destroy the machine is crucial to the final act.

### In *Demon: the Descent* and the second edition New World of Darkness games, the God Machine takes on a much greater significance.

In **Demon: the Descent**, the God Machine and its angels are the primary antagonist group for the Unchained, who themselves once served the God Machine as agents before Falling and going rogue in pursuit of their own personal Paradises or Hells.

In **The God Machine Chronicle**, which is an interim book standing in for the forthcoming *World of Darkness Second Edition*, the God Machine serves as the driver for an entire set of adventures involving the secret demiurge of the world.

In **Vampire: The Requiem Second Edition,** the God Machine is given as one possible cause for the anticovenant known as VII.

Comment: @Jadasc I'm sure you're aware of this, but WW seems to have started [an official chronicle detailing the God Machine](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/108003/God-Machine-Chronicle-Anthology) etc. I haven't had the chance to read it yet... except for the excerpt whose "The Truth" section confirms that it all was just mysterious, mad rambling... until now. Do you think it would be worth updating the Q and your A somehow? Or start a new one and reference that one here in an edit?

Comment: @Jadasc Thought you might want to see this (if you haven't already): http://paintagram.deviantart.com/art/Teloch-Vovin-370234555 :)

Comment: @Jadasc Thanks! Should you perhaps write a review of it all someplace outside rpg.SE, let me/us know. :)

Comment: The God Machine also shows up in the Appendix (Mini adventure) at the end of Promethean:Saturnine Night.
(If you would like to edit that into your answer @Jadasc)

Comment: Hi Jadasc, the bounty is ending soon. Do you have anything else to add?

Comment: @Pureferret There you go. A top-level update.